# SQL query to count rows based on condition? Keep getting syntax error for my count logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, sum

```
select sum(bookID) as totalbooks, count(bookstatus = R) as returnedbooks
from library with (nolock)
where 
   librarylocation = 'Chesterfield'
   --and bookstatus = R
```

So I want my query to return how many books total as a column, but how many books are returned as a column. I'm using count also applying a condition, but I'm getting error saying:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the syntax error `count(bookstatus = R)`

You can convert it like below

```
select sum(bookID) as totalbooks, SUM(CASE WHEN bookstatus = R THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as returnedbooks
from library with (nolock)
where librarylocation = 'Chesterfield'
--and bookstatus = R
```

Comment: `... SUM(bookID) as totalbooks` or `... COUNT(bookID) as totalbooks`?

Comment: `SUM(1)` is equivalent to `COUNT`, both works